# Need help creating clickable url link for google map's infowindow

Tags: javascript

I'm unable to create a clickable url link for Google Map's infowindow.  I'm sure it's a syntax error, just not sure where exactly.

Here's a snippet of my code

```
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map,
                      title: eventName,
                      position: loc
                        });
                        var content =
                            "<strong>" + "@location.venue_name" + "</strong><br>" +
                            "@location.venue_address" + " " + "@location.city_name" + "<br>" +
                            "@location.description" + "<br>" +

                            "@location.url" +  "<br>" + //displays url eg. 'www.google.com'

                            //"<a href=" + "@location.url" + "target="_blank">More Details</a><br>";  // map won't show if this line is uncommented 

                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, content) {
                            return function () {
                                infowindow.setContent(content);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            };
                        })(marker, content));
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `"@location.url" + "</div>" +`

Comment: that extra </div> was left by mistake, I edited it out of the original post.

Comment: I think you need to add escaped quotes (or single quotes) around the url and _blank and a space after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
var content =
    "<strong>" + "@location.venue_name" + "</strong><br>" +
    "@location.venue_address" + " " + "@location.city_name" + "<br>" +
    "@location.description" + "</div>" +
    "@location.url" +  "<br>" +
    "<a href='" + "@location.url" + "' target='_blank'>More Details</a><br>";
```

Notice I have changed quotes a little bit in the last line. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, that worked.  I had tried something like that earlier but with the single quote after the double quote.  Putting the single quote before the double quote fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

syntax got a bit messy there on content variable.

change your line as follows

`<a href='" + "@location.url" + "' target='_blank'>More Details</a><br>"`

also take a look at template literals for js which will make you code much more readable with a "`" (backtick)

```
var content = `<strong>${@location.venue_name}</strong>
               <br>
               ${@location.venue_address} ${@location.city_name} ${@location.url}
               <a href='${@location.url}' target='_blank'>More details</a>
              `
```

this way you can avoid a lot of mess trying to build a string. `${}` will allow you to put Js variables inside a backticked string.

Comment: you also need quotes around href

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Yup just seen it now :D. thank you, corrected it now :)

Answer (score 0):

preferably in one single string :

```
"<a href='@location.url' target='_blank'>More Details</a><br>"
```

thats easier for the eyes

pretty sure the @... injections works in longer strings as well